# The inverse matrix of a transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be a transformation matrix $B \rightarrow B'$.
I discovered that $M^{-1}$ is the opposite transformation.

What makes it true? (or, How can it be explained?)

Comment: What is $B$? A basis?

Comment: I'm not sure what "opposite transformations" are, but they sound like *inverse transformations* and that's the definition of $M^{-1}$'s relationship to $M$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is a matrix of a vector $x$ in the basis $B$ then its matrix $X'$ in B' is
$$X'=MX$$
but in this case we have 
$$X=M^{-1}X'$$
hence $M^{-1}$ is the transformation matrix $B'\to B$.